# Enable filter blur for multiple element in Html Css

Tags: html, css, sass

I asked a question today that I did not get exactly what I wanted.

[myQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72767378/blur-parent-but-child-not-inherit-in-html-css)

Now if I have multiple div tags and one P tag, how do I blur them?

for example :

```
<div>
     <div>
          <div>
               <div>
                    <p> text </p>
               </div>     
          </div>           
     </div>
</div>
```

styles :

```
div{
     filter:blur(5px);
   }
 p{
    filter:blur(0px)
  }
```

I mean, apply a blur filter to the first div and blur the three divs inside, but do not blur the p tag.

Comment: add `!important` to your `<p>`

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wrap your styles into a styles tag.

Comment: I wrote before  !important  has no effect

Comment: As in the duplicate: you can't. Filters will affect anything inside a parent container. You would need to create different markup for this to work.

Comment: Not possible to unblur an element once its parent has been blurred

Comment: how  i create different markup for this to work?